# conformal changes of Lorentzian metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Let $M= \mathbb R \times M_0$ with $M_0$ a smooth compact manifold with smooth boundary and let $g=-dt^2+g_0(t,x)$ be a Lorentzian metric on $M$, with $g_0$ a family of Riemannian metrics on $M_0$ that depend smoothly on time. Assume also that $(M,g)$ does not have any conjugate points along null geodesics.

My question is as follows: Is it possible to find a conformal factor $c>0$ such that $(M,cg)$ does not have any conjugate points along spacelike geodesics.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Lorentzian geometry, so please forgive me if this is non-sense: for this to work in the Lorentzian setting, it would have to work in the Riemannian setting in the first place, no? In that case, how about the case where $M_0$ is a torus with a disc removed. Wouldn't this have at least one closed geodesic, regardless of the metric, say by minimising in the right homology class? (If you do not require $\partial M_0 \neq \emptyset$ then $M_0$ could be a two-sphere.)

Comment: Indeed you are right. Perhaps I am missing some topological condition to make the problem non-trivial. Something like $M_0$ being simply connected.